# SQL teradata search for a string in a column and create a new column

Tags: sql, regex, search, teradata-sql-assistant

I have data like below. I want to search for some text in column2 and column3 and create new columns if those texts are found. I want to search for two words as below

1. america - simple string search
2. ACH - regex search as ACH is an
       abbreviation and I don't want to return words like `beach, peach` etc.
       I would like to find words like `ACH, ACH., ACH?` etc

[image]

output that I want is as below

[image]

1. column `america` has 1 on the first row because `america`was found
   in `column2` and `column3`
2. column `ach` has 1 on the last row because `ach` was found in
   `column2`

I tried couple of links but they explain how to filter data based upon particular keyword search. I would like to know how to create columns based upon keyword search.

-------------------------------------update 1

1. would below code work?
2. would it ignore case of the data?

   `select column3, column2,`

   ```
   CASE WHEN column3 like '%america%' THEN 1

   WHEN  column2 like '%america%' THEN 2

   ELSE 0

   END as Find ,



   CASE WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(column3,'\bach\b')='audit' THEN 1

   WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(column2,'\bach\b')='audit' THEN 2

   ELSE 0

   END as match2,



   (Find+match2) as summation



   from r00


   where summation>1
   ```